# How does one effectively manage the behavior and visibility state of multiple custom drop-down DOM-elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events, element

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.body-ct .selector{display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center;border:1px solid navy;border-radius:4px;}
.body-ct .selector:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.body-ct .selector h4{padding:5px 0;}
.body-ct .selector {position:relative;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown{display:none;position:absolute;top:55px;z-index:2;width:200px;border:3px solid red;background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown.active{display:block;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul{list-style-type:none;text-align:left;background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li{background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li:hover{font-weight:700;}
```

```html
<section class="body-ct">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 sel-ct">
        <div class="story-type-sel selector">
          <h4>Story Type</h4>
          <div class="dropdown story-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-type="article">Article</li>
              <li data-type="pr">Press Release</li>
              <li data-type="analyst">Analyst Report</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="year-sel selector">
          <h4>Year</h4>
          <div class="dropdown year-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-year="2021">2021</li>
              <li data-year="2020">2020</li>
              <li data-year="2019">2019</li>
              <li data-year="2018">2018</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm unable to reference the `dropdown` class from within my event listener. I think this has something to do with using `.target` or `.currentTarget`, but I'm not sure how to put it together.

When a user clicks on the element with `.selector`, then a dropdown menu should show by adding an `.active` class.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".selector").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.querySelector(".dropdown").classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

Here's the same thing in jQuery, but I don't want to use jQuery.

```
$(".selector").on("click", function () {
  $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Is the question invalid?

Comment: Actually, what you want? Do you want to add the class `active` by clicking?

Comment: Yes. That is the goal.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add your HTML code to your question.

Comment: You don't want to add within a `forEach` loop an ever-new created handler to each `item`, but you want to write the handler function once and register its reference instead. The `event`-argument of the handler has a [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)-property which does refer to the clicked element.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - But I need to iterate over all the `.selector` classes and if clicked, then set the `.dropdown' class to active. I've updated the question with the same idea, but with jQuery. However, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: `event.target` is the same as `this` in jQuery event handler

Comment: I know. I didn't forget about you @PeterSeliger. I was still working through the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array of all the `dropdown` element in your code, and `document.querySelector()` returns the first one he founds, but not necessary the one inside the element that fired the event.

If you want to add the `active` class to the dropdown element contained within the `selector` element that was clicked, you can call `querySelector()` from the event current target rather than from `document` :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.querySelector('.dropdown').classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll returns a node list. use forEach.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target.querySelectorAll(".dropdown").forEach((dopdownItem) => {
      dopdownItem.classList.add("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.body-ct .selector {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.body-ct .selector:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.body-ct .selector h4 {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.body-ct .selector {
  position: relative;
}

.body-ct .selector .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.body-ct .selector .dropdown.active {
  display: block;
}

.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<section class="body-ct">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 sel-ct">
        <div class="story-type-sel selector">
          <h4>Story Type</h4>
          <div class="dropdown story-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-type="article">Article</li>
              <li data-type="pr">Press Release</li>
              <li data-type="analyst">Analyst Report</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="year-sel selector">
          <h4>Year</h4>
          <div class="dropdown year-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-year="2021">2021</li>
              <li data-year="2020">2020</li>
              <li data-year="2019">2019</li>
              <li data-year="2018">2018</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive/basic event and state/appearance handling approach might somehow look like the next one ...

```js
function deactivateDropdown(elm) {
  elm.classList.remove('active');
}
function activateDropdown(elm) {
  elm.classList.add('active');
}

function deactivateAnyDropdown() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.dropdown')
    .forEach(deactivateDropdown);
}
function handleSelectorClick(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();

  deactivateAnyDropdown();
  activateDropdown(
    evt
      .currentTarget
      .querySelector('.dropdown')
  );
}

function init() {
  document
    .body
    .addEventListener('click', deactivateAnyDropdown)

  document
    .querySelectorAll('.selector')
    .forEach(item =>
      item.addEventListener('click', handleSelectorClick)
    );
}
init();
```

```css
.body-ct .selector{display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center;border:1px solid navy;border-radius:4px;}
.body-ct .selector:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.body-ct .selector h4{padding:5px 0;}
.body-ct .selector {position:relative;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown{display:none;position:absolute;top:55px;z-index:2;width:200px;border:3px solid red;background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown.active{display:block;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul{list-style-type:none;text-align:left;background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li{background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li:hover{font-weight:700;}
```

```html
<section class="body-ct">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 sel-ct">
        <div class="story-type-sel selector">
          <h4>Story Type</h4>
          <div class="dropdown story-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-type="article">Article</li>
              <li data-type="pr">Press Release</li>
              <li data-type="analyst">Analyst Report</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="year-sel selector">
          <h4>Year</h4>
          <div class="dropdown year-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-year="2021">2021</li>
              <li data-year="2020">2020</li>
              <li data-year="2019">2019</li>
              <li data-year="2018">2018</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

... it provides basic support for the deactivation of not currently used/clicked-on drop-downs.

But the above behavior, of cause, is far from ideal. Thus a more advanced approach would focus around just a single element which in this case is the trigger of the dropdown classified by the OP as `.selector`.

One wants the `active`-class also be part of this element and instead of `add`ing and/or `remove`ing this class one rather would `toggle` it.

One of cause then needs to accordingly change the css-selector for the related toggle-behavior.

The above example code then changes to the following one ...

```js
function deactivateDropdown(elm) {
  elm.classList.remove('active');
}
function toggleDropdown(elm) {
  elm.classList.toggle('active');
}

function deactivateAnyNonActiveDropdown(evt) {
  const { currentTarget, target } = evt;
  Array
    .from(
      document.querySelectorAll('.selector')
    )
    .filter(elm =>
      elm !== currentTarget ||
      elm
        .querySelector('.dropdown')
        .contains(target)
    )
    .forEach(deactivateDropdown);
}
function handleSelectorClick(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();

  deactivateAnyNonActiveDropdown(evt);
  toggleDropdown(evt.currentTarget);
}

function init() {
  document
    .body
    .addEventListener('click', deactivateAnyNonActiveDropdown)

  document
    .querySelectorAll('.selector')
    .forEach(item =>
      item.addEventListener('click', handleSelectorClick)
    );
}
init();
```

```css
.body-ct .selector{display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center;border:1px solid navy;border-radius:4px;}
.body-ct .selector:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.body-ct .selector h4{padding:5px 0;}
.body-ct .selector {position:relative;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown{display:none;position:absolute;top:55px;z-index:2;width:200px;border:3px solid red;background-color:#FFF;}
/*.body-ct .selector .dropdown.active{display:block;}*/
.body-ct .selector.active .dropdown {display:block;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul{list-style-type:none;text-align:left;background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li{background-color:#FFF;}
.body-ct .selector .dropdown ul li:hover{font-weight:700;}
```

```html
<section class="body-ct">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 sel-ct">
        <div class="story-type-sel selector">
          <h4>Story Type</h4>
          <div class="dropdown story-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-type="article">Article</li>
              <li data-type="pr">Press Release</li>
              <li data-type="analyst">Analyst Report</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="year-sel selector">
          <h4>Year</h4>
          <div class="dropdown year-selector">
            <ul>
              <li data-year="2021">2021</li>
              <li data-year="2020">2020</li>
              <li data-year="2019">2019</li>
              <li data-year="2018">2018</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```